# Sidekiq Rails issue. Hourly email data is not correct but if manually triggered throug async function result is correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I had been trying to resolve this issue since a month ago. It is much appreciated if someone helps me out.

I have scheduled hourly emails through sidekiq.

**My issue** is that when this hourly worker sends email, the data it takes from database is not correct. My functions are correct, I have tested result through console and result is fine with same functions.
Secondly If I trigger email manually using perform_async method, even then the result is fine but whenever that scheduler runs, it sometimes give fine results but most of the times inaccurate result. I need an expert opinion.

This is my worker function.

```
def perform
  u = User.find_by_email("abc@gmail.com")
  SensorMailer.sample_email(u).deliver
end
```

This is my mailer function

```
def sample_email(user)
  @user  = user
  @date = 1.hour.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
  @hour = 1.hour.ago.strftime("%H")


  mail(to:@user.email, subject: "#{@user.username.capitalize}'s Machine Updates at #{Time.zone.now}", cc: ["ab2@gmail.com"])
end
```

This is my mailer View

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="container">
  <h1><%= @user.username.capitalize if @user.username.present?%>'s Data </h1>
  <hr>
  <% @user.machines.each do |m| %>
    <% @machine_decorator = MachineDecorator.new(m.specific, @date, @hour) %>

    <% @machine_decorator.create_hourly_stat %>



    <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6" style="padding:0px !important;">
        <div class="panel-heading"><%= m.name.capitalize if m.name.present?%>'s Data (<%= @machine_decorator.default_hour + '--' + @machine_decorator.default_date %>) </div>
        <% offtime = m.offtimes.where("date=?", @date).first%>
        <div class="panel-body ">

            <table class="table table-striped">
            <tbody>
            <col width="20">
            <col width="80">
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Total On Time:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @machine_decorator.total_uptime %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Total Monitored Time:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @machine_decorator.total_monitored_time %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Efficiency:</strong></td>
                <td><%= @machine_decorator.efficiency(@date,@hour)%></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Max Continuous On Time:</strong></td>
                <td><%#= @machine_decorator.cont_on_time %></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><strong>Max Continuous Off Time:</strong></td>
                <td><%#= @machine_decorator.cont_off_time %></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% @machine_decorator = nil %>
  <% end %>
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

whenever an email is sent I also store data in database that is sent during this email. This function is called in mailer view, see above code, i.e (<% @machine_decorator.create_hourly_stat %>)

```
def create_hourly_stat
    HourlyStat.create(machine_id: @machine.acting_as.id, 
                      datee: @default_date, 
                      hour: @default_hour, 
                      total_monitored_time: self.total_monitored_time,
                      total_datums: self.total_datums,
                      total_uptime: self.total_uptime,

                      )
end
```

Other functions used above are :-

```
def total_datums
    #return 0 if !has_data?

    dats = self.machine.datums.find_by_date(self.default_date)

    if self.default_hour.present?
        dats = dats.by_hour(self.default_hour)
    end

    dats.count 
end
```

and

```
def total_monitored_time
    return 0 if !has_data?

    dats = @machine.datums.find_by_date(@default_date)

    if @default_hour.present?
        dats = dats.by_hour(@default_hour)
    end

    d = dats.count  
    d = d*60/60

    hrs   = d / 60
    mins  = d % 60

    final = hrs.to_s + "h " + mins.to_s + "m"
end
```

correct result is (that comes in email):

> Mg rpm's Data (18--2016-12-21)
>
> Total On Time             :   0h 50m
>
> Total Monitored Time      :   1h 0m
>
> Efficiency                :   83.33
>
> Max Continuous On Time    :
>
> Max Continuous Off Time   :

Wrong result is (in Email):

Mg rpm's Data (09--2016-12-21)

> Total On Time:    0h 0m
>
> Total Monitored Time: 0h 0m
>
> Efficiency:   0.0
>
> Max Continuous On Time:
>
> Max Continuous Off Time:

When I print this mailing content on my site to debug, I see content like this(given below). For some times it is correct but for some it shows 0.

**NOTE: I have observed that once my data is coming zero and my sidekiq is restarted then I start getting correct results again but after 5-6 hrs it again sends me wrong results.**

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming that the inaccurate data is time related. Could you provide sample data for both accurate and inaccurate results?

Comment: whenever a mail is sent, I store that sent email data in a new table for debugging purposes along with the hour and date as initialized in mailer function 
date = 1.hour.ago.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
hour = 1.hour.ago.strftime("%H")

If I resend the email for the hour from which data is inaccurate, I get accurate data then with same hour and date. Code is same but result is different.

Comment: I understand that, include data and show how your storing email data.

Comment: I have updated my question with more details. Please read it again. Now it contains all the information that you need.

Comment: This information might help you to help me.

I have observed that once my data is coming zero and my sidekiq is restarted then I start getting correct results again but after 5-6 hrs it again sends me wrong results.

Comment: Still having trouble differentiating what you're trying to accomplish from the technical issue. However, I will provide one piece of advice. If your time is wrong when using a background processor and you care about the moment the processor does something, you should be passing time parameters within your `perform`. Otherwise, your job could run several days later and `Time.now` will be evaluated much later then when the job was enqueued. Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: I just want to print total entries of data in my database in given hour on a given data. But alot many times result shows 0 but actually there were entries in database in that hours.
I use this in my worker to schedule jobs for email every hour.
recurrence do
    hourly(1)
 end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131187/discussion-between-fbelanger-and-omair-azam).

Comment: Can you put some light on this.

"NOTE: I have observed that once my data is coming zero and my sidekiq is restarted then I start getting correct results again but after 5-6 hrs it again sends me wrong results."

Comment: Actually data enters in database and emails show 0 value then I restart my sidekiq and every hour after that I see valid result i.e not 0. As many hours pass by I again get the 0 values for each hour that pass by.

Can you read anything from this information?